# WordPress: add_meta_box error

Tags: php, wordpress

I rewrite the WordPress example to create a meta box, using functions as variables:

```
$myplugin_add_meta_box = function() {
    add_meta_box('myplugin_sectionid', 'Testing', $myplugin_meta_box_callback, 'page' );
};

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', $myplugin_add_meta_box );

$myplugin_meta_box_callback = function( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
    _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
};
```

But this error appear:

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   no array or string given in
>   /var/www/public/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 1037

I believe the error has something to do with the use of function as a variable.

Comment: please change your code as i suggested in my answer & let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('myplugin_sectionid', 'Testing', 'myplugin_meta_box_callback', 'page' );
}
function myplugin_meta_box_callback ( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
    _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
};
```

Declare **myplugin_meta_box_callback** as a function, not as a variable.

Comment: In this way, the error is: Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myplugin_meta_box_callback' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/public/wp-admin/includes/template.php on line 1037

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
add_meta_box('myplugin_sectionid', 'Testing', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\myplugin_meta_box_callback', 'page' );
```

Comment: @Milap Yes. And change the line above.

Comment: great, can you please accept my answer to make it complete ?